# D3 circle around mouse cursor not appearing

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to replicate [this](http://bl.ocks.org/tgk/6068367) example in D3 v5. Specifically I am only trying to replicate the circle around the mouse cursor and removal of existing nodes/circles.

1. In the code below I got five circles to spawn but there is no circle appearing around my mouse cursor.
2. The second issue I noticed is that when the simulation begins I can remove nodes/circles by clicking on them. However, 10 seconds after the simulation begins I can no longer remove any nodes/circles. I'm not sure why this is occurring.

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

.cursor {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
}

</style>
<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>



<script>

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
      width = +1000- margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", '1000px')
    .attr("height", '1000px')
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}])
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody()) 
    .on("tick", tick);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");


var cursor = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
    .attr("class", "cursor");


restart();

function mousemove() {
  cursor.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.mouse(this) + ")");
}

function mousedownNode(d, i) {
  nodes.splice(i, 1);
  d3.event.stopPropagation();

  restart();
}

function tick() {

     var u = d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)

  u.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("r", 5)
    .merge(u)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })

  u.exit().remove()

}


function restart() {
  node = node.data(nodes);

  node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor")
      .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("r", 5)
      .on("mousedown", mousedownNode);

  node.exit()
      .remove();

   d3.forceSimulation(nodes).restart();
}

</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
     var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
      width = +1000- margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", '1000px')
    .attr("height", '1000px')
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
  .on("mousedown", mousedownCanvas)

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}])
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(50)) 
    .on("tick", tick);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

var cursor = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
    .attr("class", "cursor");

restart();

function mousemove() {
  cursor.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.mouse(this) + ")");
}

function mousedownNode(d, i) {
  nodes.splice(i, 1);
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  restart();
}
    
function mousedownCanvas() {
  var point = d3.mouse(this),
      node = {x: point[0], y: point[1]},
      n = nodes.push(node);

  restart();
}

function tick() {
    d3.selectAll(".node")
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
}


function restart() {
  let update = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes);
  
  let exit = update.exit()
      .remove();
  
    let enter = update.enter()
    .append("circle")
   .merge(update)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .on("mousedown", mousedownNode)

   force.nodes(nodes);
   force.alpha(1).restart();
}
```

```css
 body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    
    
    .cursor {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This part of your code removes the cursor circle, as it selects all circles in the graph, and removes any that aren't associated to the data. If you change the selection to be based on the class of circles that are nodes then it won't remove the cursor circle

```
var u = d3.select('svg')
.selectAll('.node')
.data(nodes)
```

Your code is missing the mousedownCanvas function, and its assingment to the svg canvas, so you can't add any new nodes

```
svg.on("mousedown", mousedownCanvas)
```

Also, your code did not have the d3 selection and data join working properly, and was replicated in the tick function - see the working example below where new/removed nodes are handled in the enter and exit selection within update()